# Unable To Install Packages With NPM Due To Corporate Proxy

Tags: npm, set, registry, config

npm install gulp-cli@2.3.0 --global, however getting the below error which states that - "This is a problem related to network connectivity. If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly."

[image]

Unable To Install Packages With NPM Due To Corporate Proxy